Assistance Needed with DAX Measure for Calculating Sequential Distance in Power BI
I am currently facing difficulties creating a DAX measure(or python script, or something else) to calculate the local distance between the most recent activity and the previous one, with all the data already present in a single table. Despite extensive research, all the examples I’ve found involve two tables, which doesn't apply to my situation.
The table contains the following columns: the ID of the card that performed the activity, the activity ID, the location ID, the registration date (note that an activity may start on the 10th, for example, but the relevant date is the end date, so in this case, the date would actually be the 11th), start and end date/time, latitude, and longitude.
The goal is for the user to be able to filter the data by the card ID and then by the registration date. Once filtered, the data should be organised by date and time, and the measure I intend to create should calculate the distance from the location of the previous record.
I realise this might sound a bit confusing, so let me clarify with some example data:



ID_CARD
ID_ACTIVITY
ID_LOCATION
CALDAY
STARTTIME
ENDTIME
LATITUDE
LONGITUDE




A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX16
X1
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 03:51
11/08/2024 04:02
41.00000
-8.00000


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX1
X2
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 04:07
11/08/2024 04:17
41.00001
-8.00001


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX2
X3
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 04:29
11/08/2024 04:59
41.00002
-8.00002


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX3
X4
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 06:19
11/08/2024 06:44
41.00003
-8.00003


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX4
X4
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 07:37
11/08/2024 08:10
41.00004
-8.00004


B
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX5
X6
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 07:54
11/08/2024 08:58
41.00005
-8.00005


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX6
X6
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 08:37
11/08/2024 08:40
41.00006
-8.00006


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX7
X7
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 08:40
11/08/2024 09:45
41.00007
-8.00007


B
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX8
X5
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 18:06
11/08/2024 18:32
41.00008
-8.00008


B
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX9
XX7
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 18:33
11/08/2024 18:56
41.00009
-8.00009


B
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX10
X7
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 18:57
11/08/2024 19:34
41.00010
-8.00010


B
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX11
X9
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 19:35
11/08/2024 19:59
41.00011
-8.00011


B
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX12
X2
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 20:01
11/08/2024 20:21
41.00012
-8.00012


B
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX13
X3
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 20:23
11/08/2024 21:37
41.00013
-8.00013


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX14
X8
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 20:57
11/08/2024 22:00
41.00014
-8.00014


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX15
X9
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 22:03
11/08/2024 22:34
41.00015
-8.00015



Let's suppose that these are the data stored in the database.
Now I will show what the user will see when filtering on the dashboard.



ID_CARD
ID_ACTIVITY
ID_LOCATION
CALDAY
STARTTIME
ENDTIME
LATITUDE
LONGITUDE
.distanceKM




A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX16
X1
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 03:51
11/08/2024 04:02
41.00000
-8.00000
0.0


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX1
X2
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 04:07
11/08/2024 04:17
41.00001
-8.00001
0.2


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX2
X3
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 04:29
11/08/2024 04:59
41.00002
-8.00002
0.4


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX3
X4
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 06:19
11/08/2024 06:44
41.00003
-8.00003
0.7


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX4
X4
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 07:37
11/08/2024 08:10
41.00004
-8.00004
0.0


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX6
X6
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 08:37
11/08/2024 08:40
41.00006
-8.00006
1.0


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX7
X7
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 08:40
11/08/2024 09:45
41.00007
-8.00007
0.9


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX14
X8
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 20:57
11/08/2024 22:00
41.00014
-8.00014
0.2


A
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX15
X9
11/08/2024
11/08/2024 22:03
11/08/2024 22:34
41.00015
-8.00015
0.5



This is what the user will see when applying the filters; the .distanceKM will be calculated in the order of the records.
I hope this is enough for you to understand my question. I look forward to the resolution of this issue or even a suggestion.
P.S.: I had to create random data to protect confidential information, but I think the idea is clear.

Try a Measure similar to:
.distanceKM = 
  var thisLat = MAX('YourTable'[LATITUDE])
  var thisLng = MAX('YourTable'[LONGITUDE])
  var prevRow = OFFSET(-1, DISTINCT(ALLSELECTED('YourTable')), ORDERBY([ENDTIME], ASC))
  var prevLat = CALCULATE(MAX('YourTable'[LATITUDE]), prevRow)
  var prevLng = CALCULATE(MAX('YourTable'[LONGITUDE]), prevRow)

  // from 2nd answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21623206/21688343
  var r = 6371 // Earth's radius in KM
  var p = DIVIDE( PI(), 180 )
  var a = 0.5 - DIVIDE(COS( (thisLat - prevLat) * p), 2) + COS(prevLat * p) * COS(thisLat * p) * DIVIDE(1 - COS((thisLng - prevLng) * p), 2)
  var dist = 2 * r * ASIN(SQRT(a))

  return IF(NOT ISBLANK(prevLat), dist, 0)

The main part is using OFFSET to get the previous row.
See https://pbidax.wordpress.com/2022/12/23/introducing-dax-window-functions-part-2/ for a good write-up on it.
